# Shrinking top half of webpage on scroll smoothly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a requirement to make it so when you scroll the page the top half of the page shrinks down until a min-height (25vh). Once the min-height is reached it no longer shrinks and the bottom snaps to 75vh and becomes overflow:auto so you can scroll and you always see the top and bottom.

I figured out how to achieve this but it's really jittery. You see this effect on mobile apps often and especially like Google Maps where you scroll, the map or place images shrink down which are up top and then at some threshold the bottom scrolls up.

The requirements are technically met with what I have but it's not a very good UX. The way I achieve this is that I take the scroll position and take the difference of the scroll position and the initial heights of the elements to create a new height (i.e. if top half is 100px tall and you scroll 25px down 100px-25px= new height of 75px).

The important part though is you can't just decrease the height because then the content gets smaller and it always fits vertically preventing you from scrolling back up and making the top half taller again. So to fix that I added a top margin of the scroll amount. So, in my 100px/25px example the margin top is 25px allowing you to scroll back up 25px.

The margin piece though is what is causing jitters and making it look just janky.

How can I do this smoothly?

```js
var $topElement = $('.top-section');
var $bottomElement = $('.bottom-section');
var windowHeight = $(this).innerHeight();
var initialTopHeight = $topElement.height();
var initialBottomHeight = $bottomElement.height();

$(window).on('scroll', function () {
    var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop()

    var newTopHeight = initialTopHeight - scrollTop;
    var newBottomHeight = initialBottomHeight - scrollTop;

    if (windowHeight*.25 <= newTopHeight) {
        $topElement.css({
            height: newTopHeight,
            marginTop: scrollTop
        })
        $bottomElement.css({
            height: newBottomHeight
        })
    }
    else {
        $topElement.css({
            height: '25vh',
            marginTop: scrollTop
        })
        $bottomElement.css({
            height: '75vh',
            overflow: 'auto'
        })
    }

})
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.min-height.wrapper {
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.inner-wrapper {
    position: relative;
}

.toolbar {
    position:absolute;
    background: #ffffff77;
    box-shadow: #000000dd 0 0px 15px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
}

.top-section {
    height: 100vh;
    background: url(https://www.bing.com/th?id=OHR.RedSailboat_EN-US1173520356_1920x1080.jpg&rf=LaDigue_1920x1080.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

.min-height .bottom-section {
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: auto;
}

.bottom-section ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.bottom-section li {
    padding: 10px;
}

.bottom-section li:nth-child(1n + 1) {
    background: #ff000022;
    border: 1px solid #ff000066;
}

.bottom-section li:nth-child(2n + 1) {
    background: #00ff0022;
    border: 1px solid #00ff0066;
}

.bottom-section li:nth-child(3n + 1) {
    background: #0000ff22;
    border: 1px solid #0000ff66;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="inner-wrapper">
            <div class="toolbar">
                <button>Button</button>
                <button>Button</button>
                <button>Button</button>
            </div>
            <div class="top-section">
            </div>
            <div class="bottom-section">
                <ul>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
                    <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
                    <li>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
                    <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
                    <li>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
                    <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
                    <li>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
                    <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
                    <li>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
                    <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
                    <li>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
                    <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
                    <li>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
                    <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
                    <li>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
                    <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
                    <li>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
                    <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
                    <li>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
                    <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
                    <li>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
                    <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
                    <li>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
                    <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
                    <li>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
                    <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
                    <li>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
                    <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
                    <li>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
                    <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
                    <li>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
                    <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
                    <li>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
                    <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
                    <li>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
                    <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
                    <li>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
                    <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
                    <li>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
                    <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
                    <li>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
                    <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
                    <li>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
                    <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
                    <li>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
                    <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
                    <li>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
                    <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
                    <li>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
                    <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
                    <li>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
                    <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
                    <li>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
                    <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
                    <li>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
                    <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
                    <li>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
                    <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
                    <li>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
                    <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
                    <li>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
                    <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
                    <li>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
                    <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
                    <li>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
                    <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
                    <li>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
                    <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
                    <li>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
                    <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
                    <li>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```